# How to protect my application data in any operating system?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, access-control

I have an application which generates few files and get stored locally on the system. I need to protect that generated files from getting deleted by any user in the system. By setting the permission to that particular folder containing files, still I cannot stop Admin from deleting the files. Is there any way to achieve this in Windows/Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no practical way to prevent someone with sufficient credentials from deleting the file. You can make it difficult, but you can't make it impossible unless you patch the OS and/or firmware yourself. And without trying to sound too condescending, is the type of thing where if you have to ask how to do it, you won't be able to do it.

This is as it should be: the user owns the computer, you don't. They should have complete control over it.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan, for a quick response. :) That make sense, any external application can't block system owner to access something.

Comment: Even if you did patch the OS and firmware, the user can always pull out the disk drive and hit it with a hammer. :-)

Comment: Patching the OS will be *very* hard for closed source OSes like Windows and OSX. And you'd have to make a user run your patched version. Mnemonic: "eUID 0 is omnipotent. Big full stop !"